# How to wait for an alert in Selenium webdriver ?

Tags: java, selenium, alert, selenium-webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [selenium 2.4.0, how to check for presence of an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076758/selenium-2-4-0-how-to-check-for-presence-of-an-alert)

I am using the following code to close the alert window :

```
Alert alert3 = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert3.dismiss();
```

The alert appears a few seconds after the opening of the main window.

How can I wait and check if alert appears ?

Comment: refer my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358965/how-to-handle-authentication-alert-of-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/59611252#59611252

Answer (score 15):

No default method for waiting for alert.

but, you can write your own method something like this.

```
waitForAlert(WebDriver driver)
{
   int i=0;
   while(i++<5)
   {
        try
        {
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            break;
        }
        catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
        {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          continue;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: The client doesn't accept that we are using dead waits (Thread.sleep) he simply wouldn't accept the PR. Can't we replace it with expected conditions?

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {

  boolean presentFlag = false;

  try {

   // Check the presence of alert
   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   // Alert present; set the flag
   presentFlag = true;
   // if present consume the alert
   alert.accept();

  } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
   // Alert not present
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return presentFlag;

 }
```

Comment: This method will not wait for alert. Just it will check whether the alert is present or not .

Comment: sorry. yeah. got a lil but misconfused. 
try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310548/how-can-i-reliably-wait-for-javascript-alerts-using-selenium2-webdriver