# How to handle windows pop up or authentication pop up in Linux machine using selenium script

Tags: linux, selenium

I need help in handling windows pop up in Linux machine. It's an authentication pop-up on which I need to click 'OK' button using selenium script. I have used AutoIt which works fine in a windows machine, but same doesn't work in Linux server. There is a tool called sikuli I heard which can handle these kinda pop-ups. I need help in using this tool or any other tool which does the job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Did you tried to use embedded `selenium` method to accept alert?

Comment: Andersson, no, I haven't tried embedded selenium method. Can you send across few links or script that I can go through? Appreciate you help.

Comment: @ravi, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448173/selenium-automatically-accepting-alerts

Comment: @Andersson, above link which you have mentioned talks about alert pop up. I am having issues with lithium pop up (i.e authentication pop up). I  was able to handle this pop up on linux machine using Sikuli, but we are running these scripts through Sauce Labs, where Sikuli tool fails to run through SauceLabs. Does anyone know any other tool which can handle windows pop up in saucelabs?