# Using Selenium with Java to automate VM Remote Console

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, vmware, ui-automation

I am using Selenium WebDriver to automate VMWare HML5. When I get to the end to launch the VM Remote Console there is an alert message that I can not inspect to click on the message. There are two choices  1) "Open VM Ware Remote Console" 2)"Don't open" I've tried the following:

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
 alert.accept();
```

I got the following error:

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=C:\Users\USERNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir18824_10625}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.101, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 35b8e59a225daf47796fe483450924f0
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:694)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:1020)
    at browser.VMTasks.launchRemoteConsole(VMTasks.java:624)
    at bro
```

wser.html5TEST.main(html5TEST.java:80)

I also tried to sendKeys to TAB to the correct choice and ENTER since the focus is on the alert and the rest of the page can not be interacted with while the alert is there but nothing is working for the popup alert.

Comment: did you precede that by a wait until the alert is present?

Comment: Yes, I have the following code before the Alert code:      
        synchronized(driver){driver.wait(5000);}

Comment: Maybe try with a wait until the alert is present (there are examples of that on stack overflow) as opposed to the timing way. But likely then that is not the issue, sorry.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448173/selenium-automatically-accepting-alerts gives a technique for the wait that may work and even if not may give you info on what the problem is

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this for me. I was able to use Robot to send tabs and enter since I couldn't inspect the alert as if it wasn't a part of the html code on the main page.