# Handling alerts in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario in which clicking on "Save" button can give three different alerts based on the data entered. It can give "Saved successfully", "User already registered" and "Username already exist" alerts. I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr5995_View_btnsavesession")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String A = alert.getText();
    if (A == "Username already exist"){
        System.out.println("Admission number already exist.");
        alert.accept();
    } else if (A == "User already registered"){
        System.out.println("User already registered");
        alert.accept();
    } else if (A == "Saved Successfully."){
        System.out.println("Saved Successfully.");
        alert.accept();
    }
```

But it is showing No Alert present exception. I have tried increasing the sleep time but still it shows the same exception.

Comment: Is it a browser controlled alert or is it an html popup?

Comment: ajax pop up alerts and browser controlled alerts are used in this application

Comment: @Dinu: Can you share the HTML for the Save button and the JavaScript method if it's calling anything behind the scenes?

Comment: This is the html- '<a id="dnn_ctr5995_View_btnsavesession" class="dnnPrimaryAction savescroll" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("dnn$ctr5995$View$btnsavesession", "", true, "a", "", false, true))">Save</a>'

Comment: The id posted in the code and in the html tag are different? Is this cause of the problem?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639280/how-to-wait-for-an-alert-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Vignesh as I have already mentioned in the question, I have tried increasing wait time but still it is giving the same error.

Comment: @Dinu check wether you're pointing the alert correctly. else you try window handling, since we dont know what type of alert it is

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using `==` instead of `.equalsIgnoreCase()`? With `==` operator this code should not work.

Comment: @Zhuinden it was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you never actually call `alert.accept()` because you're using `A == "User already registered"` instead of `"User already registered".equalsIgnoreCase(A)`. If you change the `if` conditions, that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your clicking is not actually clicking because the 'save' id is no like in the element.
Try to do it like this:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*=save"])).click();
```

And then trying to catch the alert. Please note the '*' in selector.

Comment: this is an incorrect CSS selector `:)`  It needs to be wrapped in `[]` if you are trying to identify an attribute.  e.g.: `[id*='save']`

Comment: sure, sorry for the typo. fixing the mistake :)

Comment: I have used the same id as mentioned in the HTML tag but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in what phase you experience the error - is the clicking working and you just can catch the alert or the clicking is not working to?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Html shared, the id of the element is not "save". So the first line of the shared code should be modified a bit to achieve the output.

Change the element identification tag to :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr5995_View_btnsavesession")).click();
```

or if the 'id' of the element is changing on every instance, then it can be changed to:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'_View_btnsavesession')]")).click();
```

Comment: I have used the same id as mentioned in the HTML tag but still it is showing the same error.