# How to Handle Browser Authentication popup using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://52.19.191.249/aur/");
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username");
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("password");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Getting message as no alert open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium - Other way to basic authenticate than via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-other-way-to-basic-authenticate-than-via-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform Basic Authentication for FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver and IEdriver in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and-iedriver)

Comment: This is not duplicate i am trying to authenticate the internal site not the hosted one

Answer (score 3):

Since `driver.switchTo().alert()` doesn't wait for alert loaded, you need to wait for it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639803/8609512

P.S. You can check it by adding a `Thread.sleep(2000);` for example, before `driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username");` sentence -- sleeps are usually a bad practice for test automation, but sometimes it could be helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this syntax and worked
driver.get("http://Username:password@52.19.191.249/aur/") ;

Answer (score 0):

Try using autoit: [its simple and effective]

The code goes something like ::

```
from selenium import webdriver
import autoit
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://sitewithpopup.com")
autoit.win_wait_active("",30) 
autoit.send("Username{TAB}")
autoit.send("Password{Enter}")
```

Since the autoit will **type whereever your cursor is** and by default the cursor is on the **userID** field so you can make use of it.