# wait for alert pop to appear after performing click on webpage without using Thread.sleep

Tags: c#, selenium

After clicking search on a webpage, alert pop up will appear.  I need to wait until the pop up  appears. i have to do without using Thread.sleep.

Answer (score 3):

ExpectedConditions class has specific wait for alert pop-up.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExpectedConditions` is obsolete, so try to use this:

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
```

[C# Selenium 'ExpectedConditions is obsolete'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wait` command:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, the drawback is there is no timeout for this one. it must be ensured that the popup will appear.

```
while (driver.WindowHandles.Count == 1)
{
    //leave it blank
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this ???

```
public static class SeleniumExtensions
{
    public static IAlert WaitAlert(this ITargetLocator locator, int seconds = 10)
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            try { return locator.Alert(); }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException) when (--seconds >= 0) { Thread.Sleep(1000); }
        }
    }
}
```

works for me:

```
var alert = _driver.SwitchTo().WaitAlert();
```

Answer (score -1):

it's a little bit rude, but work for me.

```
public IAlert WaitAlert(int timeOut)
    {
        for (int cont = timeOut; cont > 0; cont--)
        {
            try
            {
                return driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException erro)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
            }
        }
        throw new NoAlertPresentException();
    }
```